# ReactJS: create DOM on the fly

Tags: reactjs

How to transform this:

```
{dataFormat: 'hello my [friend=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship]'}
```

to this:

```
<div>
   hello my <a onClick={...} href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship">friend</a>         
</div>
```

I need to somehow be able to scan a string and create links on the fly. Any idea?

The dataFormat can contain more than one link with unknown order between "regular" text and links.

Comment: Have you tried? This is pretty straightforward with `React.createElement` instead of JSX.

Comment: Yes, I am trying, thought of using a regex. Can you elaborate on your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using regex which did the job.

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/yogepa/edit?js,output

**Code:**

```
renderSpan(content) {
    return <span>
        {content}
    </span>
}

renderLink(content) {
    const parts = content
            .replace(/\[|\]/g, '')
            .split('=');

    return <a style={ styles.link } onClick={ alert }>
        {parts[0]}
        </a>
}

renderFormat() {
    let { dataFormat } = this.state;

    const regex = /(\[[^\]]+])*([^\[]+)(\[[^\]]+])*(\[[^\]]+])*([^\[]+)(\[[^\]]+])*(\[[^\]]+])*([^\[]+)(\[[^\]]+])*/;

    const matches = regex.exec(dataFormat);

    return matches.reduce((output, match, index) => {

        if (match && index >= 2) {
            output.push(match.indexOf('[') >= 0 ?
                this.renderLink(match) :
                this.renderSpan(match)
            );
        }

        return output;
    }, []);
}
```

I probably can improve the Regex expression though.

[image: result]